# Monitor Application and Network activity in Mac OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, android-activity, monitoring

Is it possible monitor Application activity in background something like this,

When user logged-in , 
Which application being accessed and when, 
when system went to sleep,  etc.... 
when it was disconnected to network and connected to it, : I believe, for that some service can be implemented which keeps on pinging an IP or some other approach,